# How to use lineString of coordinates in HERE map?

Tags: javascript, coordinates, here-maps-rest

I have a linestring of coordinates:

```
"coordinates": "12.116821,55.7218827 12.11652,55.72172 12.11607,55.72143 12.11567,55.72115 12.1152,55.72081 12.11495,55.72061 12.11463,55.72031 12.11435,55.72003 12.11409,55.71975 12.11397,55.71959 12.11367,55.71923 12.11334,55.71882 12.11313,55.71855 12.11285,55.71818 12.11269,55.71794 12.11258,55.71774 12.112478,55.7175174"
```

which I would like to display in HERE map **but I am not sure if this linestring represents a route with spaces between each coordinates or is it just a uncut long route?**

**IF it is a route with seperations (spaces) then I would like to use it but as you can see the first and the last coordinate do not contain both latitude and longitude and I have no idea why**  (I am taking the linestrings from an API, they are all like this)